# How to inject a function into requiring file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have `main.js`:

```
function someFunc($smt){
  // Do something
}

require('./script.js');
```

and when I try run `script.js`:

```
someFunc($someParam);
```

I got an error:

```
ReferenceError: someFunc is not defined
```

How can I import functions from parent file into requiring file?

Comment: You can't. That is the opposite to how `require` works.

Comment: it's probably a design flaw if a required file needs functions from the file that is requiring it (though passing variables/functions to a function in a required file is common)

Comment: You're mistaking `require` with an include function

Comment: @Quentin are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Just, I can't make this function as global, because it's dynamicly for each requireing file

Comment: @TurarAbu — http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: main.js `function someFunc($smt){
    console.log($smt);
}

require('./script.js')(someFunc);` - script.js `module.exports = function init(someFunc) {
    someFunc(1);
}` - though, that is a very simplistic solution, because it would be a little more complex in the *real world™*

Comment: @Quentin ok, such problem: the main file require other files. These files use the same function, but for each file this function works differently. That is, the main file creates the decorator of this function, depending on the file name

Comment: you'll need a redesign then

Comment: of course there's a way though - using some *global* object (don't do it)

Comment: *I'm going to get howled at for this, but if you really really must* ... in `main.js` ... `global.someFunc = function($smt){ ... your code ... }`

Comment: Just put ```module.exports = ``` before the function definition, this ```module.exports``` function is used to export anything as you want and here is exporting a function

Comment: @SureshMahawar ... `scripts.js` doesn't require `main.js` so that won't be at all helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is beter solution for include custom arguments into requiring script:

```
// main.js

function someFunc($smt) {
  // Do something
}

$require = require;
// prepare $require for inject

$module = module;
// prepare $module for inject

var script = fs.readFileSync('./script.js', 'UTF8');
script = new Function('someFunc', 'require', 'module', script);
script.call({}, someFunc, $require, $module);
```

TODO: make global function what will prepare $require and $module variables for requested file. And then call like this:

```
const script = include(file/path);
```

Comment: This looks overly complex to me, and isn't idiomatic Node usage. In 5 years of Node development I've not seen anything like this before. Just use `require` normally.

Comment: @JedRichards Unfortunately, I can't, because I need dynamicly decorator for each file

Comment: Try and explain your problem better in the question. I'm sure there's a simple way to achieve what you need to do.

Comment: @JedRichards The main script load few files from child dir where run servers. Each server must be isolated from parent dir but have access for some core functions (the main script decides) and functions must be able for each loaded files inside servers (like global function)

Answer (score 2):

Make `script.js` export the function that does the work, and have that function accept a parameter.

In `script.js`

```
module.exports = function (f) {
  f();
}
```

Then in `main.js`

```
var script = require('./script.js');

function someFunc(){
  // Do something
}

script(someFunc);
```